# Artemis Bridges/Federation

Tags: activemq-artemis

Looking to understand differences between various options for moving messages i.e. diverts , bridges & Federation. As I understand diverts are for within same broker and can mix along with brides.Bridge on the other hand,can be used to move messages to different broker instance(JMS Compliant one).

Then Federation when I read looks similar to Bridging , where messages can be moved/pulled from upstream. Quick help on when which feature to be used is helpful.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridges are the most basic way to move messages from one broker to another. However, each bridge can only move messages from *one* queue to *one* address, and each bridge must be created manually in `broker.xml` or programmatically via the management interface. Many messaging use-cases involve dynamically created addresses and queues so manually creating bridges is not feasible. Furthermore, many messaging use-cases involve *lots* of addresses in queues and manually creating corresponding bridges would be undesirable.

Federation uses bridges behind the scenes, but it allows configuring one element in `broker.xml` to apply to lots of addresses and queues (even those created dynamically). Federation also allows upstream & downstream configurations whereas bridges can only be configured to "push" messages from one broker to another.

Comment: Thank you Justin. But what upstream or downstream in a broker topology , Its just another broker to move messages right.